Spatial join, process killed without any message
Environment: Xeon CPU, 48Gb RAM
Ubuntu with DuckDB + spatial installed
I have 2 tables, one contains a geometry column with points and second table has geometry column with lines (road segments). I need to "match", find points which depends to those road segments.
Points: 935044
Lines: 4166
my query (I took 200m, just to test):
select * from points_tbl p1 
join lines_tbl lt on ST_DWithin(p1.geom, lt.geom, 200);

After some time the DuckDB process will be just killed, without any error or any other message..
What is wrong? not enough memory? i was expecting at least some error message..
Thx
UPDATE: very strange behavior
If I add LIMIT, even very large, same as my amount of points - it works and is pretty fast:
select * from points_tbl p1 
join lines_tbl lt on ST_DWithin(p1.geom, tl.geom, 200) limit 800000;

UPDATE2: just found that must transform epsg:4326 to 3857 - to have distance in meters:
select p1.*, round(st_distance(ST_Transform(p1.geom, 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'), 
ST_Transform(lt.geom, 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857')), 2) as distance, 
lt.line_id, lt.geom from points_tbl p1 
join lines_tbl lt on 
ST_DWithin(ST_Transform(p1.geom, 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'), 
ST_Transform(lt.geom, 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'), 50) limit 10000;


You'll probably need to ask the DuckDB people directly. 1. https://github.com/duckdb/duckdb_spatial/discussions 2. https://discord.duckdb.org
